# Create secure views on snowflake

Tags: view, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table *AAA* and I have created a secure view *BBB* on top of it with definition:
 `create or replace secure view BBB as select * from AAA`

I have granted select privilege on *BBB* to a role *RRR*.

when I perform `select * from BBB` using *RRR* it throws 
`SQL compilation error: Failure during expansion of view 'BBB': SQL compilation error: Object 'AAA' does not exist or not authorized.`

Now, when I grant select privilege on *AAA* to the role *RRR*,

the same query works fine. Is it how the secure view is suppose to work?
Because in this case the table is still accessible and whatever restriction view imposes can be thrown away by accessing the table directly. It does not sound secure at all.

What am I missing here???

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the SELECT privilege on the view, you'll need to grant USAGE on the database and schema containing the view:

```
grant usage on database <yourdb> to role RRR;
grant usage on schema <yourschema> to role RRR;
```

As you pointed out, secure views wouldn't make sense if you still had to grant access to the underlying table.

Comment: Thanks for adding the missing grant statements.

But I suppose with the existing flaw snowflake secure views are not completely secure. I thought I was missing something and was providing unnecessary privileges. Would raise a snowflake issue to fix this.

Comment: Sorry, why do you think this is a flaw?

Comment: Let's say my users are using table 'AAA' currently to access data and then I bring in the secure view BBB as per the above process which filters out many columns from the table. Now the users would always query the view to get the data and would get the limited dataset only, but, if they try selecting from the table they would be able to do that and the restriction via the view becomes null and void.
This is the exact problem I am facing today and hence I call it a flaw.

Comment: You do *not* need to give access to AAA. You only need to grant USAGE on the database and schema in addition to SELECT on the view.

Comment: only with these grants:  


`grant usage on database <yourdb> to role RRR;` . 
`grant usage on schema <yourschema> to role RRR;`  
`grant select on view BBB to role RRR;`  


I still get . 
`SQL compilation error: Failure during expansion of view 'BBB': SQL compilation error: Object 'AAA' does not exist or not authorized.` . 

That is my problem. I did expect it to work without select on table, but it's not working. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Can you try specifying the fully qualified name of the table in your view? Like `select * from dbname.schemaname.tablename`.

Comment: I am using fully qualified name everywhere. Do you have any step by step guide to create a secure view?

Comment: Got the issue, it seems the role that is being used to create the secure views must have usage on db and schema and select on table. And then any role can have read on the view which works perfectly fine.

But if the select on table is removed from role that creates the view it won't work and the new role here 'RRR' must have the select privilege.

Comment: @KrishnaKumar Your observations are correct.  I've had a discussion about this in the past if you'd like to see the thread.  https://community.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z00009UuyDgSAJ/what-sort-of-grants-do-views-use-and-need

Answer (score -2):

```
USE ROLE SECURITYADMIN;
--CREATE ROLE ADMIN_ROLE
CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS ADMIN_ROLE;
GRANT USAGE ON WAREHOUSE ADMIN_WH TO ROLE ADMIN_ROLE;
GRANT ROLE ADMIN_ROLE TO ROLE SYSADMIN;

GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE EXISTING_DB TO ADMIN_ROLE;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA EXISTING_DB.EXISTING_SCHEMA TO ADMIN_ROLE;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE EXISTING_DB.EXISTING_SCHEMA.MYTABLE TO ADMIN_ROLE;

--CREATE DATA ROLES
CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS USER_ROLE;
GRANT USAGE ON WAREHOUSE USER_WH TO ROLE USER_ROLE;

--USE NEW_DB DATABASE
USE DATABASE NEW_DB;
USE ROLE ADMIN_ROLE;
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS NEW_SCHEMA
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE NEW_DB TO USER_ROLE;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA NEW_DB.NEW_SCHEMA TO USER_ROLE;
GRANT SELECT ON FUTURE VIEWS IN SCHEMA NEW_DB.NEW_SCHEMA TO USER_ROLE;

CREATE OR REPLACE SECURE VIEW NEW_DB.NEW_SCHEMA.MY_SECURE_VIEW AS SELECT * FROM EXISTING_DB.EXISTING_SCHEMA.MYTABLE

USE ROLE SECURITYADMIN;
GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE EXISTING_DB TO USER_ROLE;
GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA EXISTING_DB.EXISTING_SCHEMA TO USER_ROLE;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE EXISTING_DB.EXISTING_SCHEMA.MYTABLE TO USER_ROLE;

REVOKE USAGE ON DATABASE EXISTING_DB FROM ADMIN_ROLE;
REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA EXISTING_DB.EXISTING_SCHEMA FROM ADMIN_ROLE;
REVOKE SELECT ON TABLE EXISTING_DB.EXISTING_SCHEMA.MYTABLE FROM ADMIN_ROLE;

CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS TEAM_ROLE;
GRANT ROLE USER_ROLE TO TEAM_ROLE;

USE ROLE TEAM_ROLE;
SELECT * FROM NEW_DB.NEW_SCHEMA.MY_SECURE_VIEW
```

my use case is very close to this snippet

if I remove

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE EXISTING_DB.EXISTING_SCHEMA.MYTABLE TO ADMIN_ROLE;
```

I am unable to create the view
if I remove

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE EXISTING_DB.EXISTING_SCHEMA.MYTABLE TO USER_ROLE;
```

then

```
SELECT * FROM NEW_DB.NEW_SCHEMA.MY_SECURE_VIEW
```

fails with the exception

```
SQL compilation error: Failure during expansion of view 'NEW_DB.NEW_SCHEMA.MY_SECURE_VIEW': SQL compilation error: Object 'EXISTING_DB.EXISTING_SCHEMA.MYTABLE' does not exist or not authorized.
```

Let me know if the approach has got some basic flaws..

Comment: @d.hoeffer please check out this

Comment: No need to perform these queries:

`GRANT USAGE ON DATABASE EXISTING_DB TO USER_ROLE;`
`GRANT USAGE ON SCHEMA EXISTING_DB.EXISTING_SCHEMA TO USER_ROLE;`
`GRANT SELECT ON TABLE EXISTING_DB.EXISTING_SCHEMA.MYTABLE TO USER_ROLE;`

`REVOKE USAGE ON DATABASE EXISTING_DB FROM ADMIN_ROLE;`
`REVOKE USAGE ON SCHEMA EXISTING_DB.EXISTING_SCHEMA FROM ADMIN_ROLE;`
`REVOKE SELECT ON TABLE EXISTING_DB.EXISTING_SCHEMA.MYTABLE FROM ADMIN_ROLE;`